# What is the command that can change the text color to #000000 when clicked upon

Tags: css, colors

I don't know what the command is called to change the text color when clicked upon. I've tried different variations of `textarea:focus, input:focus` and `textarea:active, input:active` but it didn't work.

```
input, textarea {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

input: active textarea: active {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing. A click event can't be handled via `CSS`. You need `Javascript`.

Comment: You mean [like this?](http://jsbin.com/sigoti/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input:focus` will work fine, [see this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpmkps4y/).

```
<input type="text" value="Click me to make me green!">
```

CSS:

```
input {
    color:red;
    width:20em;
}
input:focus {
    color:green;
    background:#dfd;
}
```

The `:focus` state indicates that the element is currently selected and accepting input. [Read more over at W3](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:focus).

If you want to *permanently* change the color on first click you're introducing 'custom persistent state', which is not behavioral and as such not possible via CSS but only by using Javascript, for example to add a class to the element.

Answer (score 2):

There are some CSS ways to do it- like an answer here already. Here's an example with Javascript. Like it has been said, Javascript should be used if you want to permanently change the color.

**HTML**

```
<p id="change">Hello World!</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
 document.getElementById('change').onclick = changeColor;   

 function changeColor() {
    document.body.style.color = "blue";
    return false;
    }
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xzLytwq1/)